# Web Audio API Stop after delay

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I have this snippet to play a tone.  I set the delay in the `stop()` function to 5 sec.  It works the first time it is called.  But any subsequent called the delay did not occur - it just stops as soon as the time1 expired.

Any suggestions what is the problem?

```
function playSound() {
    var mySource = myAudioContext.createOscillator();
    var myGain = myAudioContext.createGainNode();

    mySource.frequency.value = 261.625;
    mySource.connect(myGain);
    myGain.gain.value = 1.0;
    myGain.connect(myAudioContext.destination);

    mySource.start(0);
    setTimeout(function(s) {
               mySource.stop(5);   //stop after 5 sec. only works for the first call
               }, time1, mySource);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

stop(n)  does not take effect "after n seconds from now."  It's an absolute time - and time starts at zero, so the first time it appears to work[*].

Use this instead:

```
mySource.stop( 5 + myAudioContext.currentTime );
```

[*] This actually also relies on a bug in Webkit/Blink right now, where we don't start time running until the first node is created; it's supposed to start when the AudioContext is created.